# The contents of the AJAX response is not written to the HTML container tags - span, div

Tags: json, jquery, html

The following jQuery function returns a correct JSON response from Spring.

```
$(function() {
    $('#dataForm').submit(function() {

        var rows;
        var form = $(this);
        rowCount(function() {
            var url = form.attr('action'),
            rows = form.find('input[name="rows"]').val();

            if(rows==0)
            {
                insert();
            }
            else if(rows==1)
            {
                update(function(response){
                    $("#textContents").val(response);
                    alert($("#textContents").val()); 
                    //Alerts the correct contents from the database
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });        
});
```

This function is called when the form is submitted.

The alert box in the `else if` condition alerts the correct contents from the server. `textContents` is a `<span></span>` id like.

```
<span id="textContents"></span>
```

Everything is fine but the response is apparently not being written to the HTML span tag for unknown reasons.

I have even removed design with all HTML templates of the current page but no clues found. If I changed the span tag to some other like `<textarea></textarea>` for demonstration, then the contents is displayed.

There are no misplaced tags on the form. I have also tried to replace `<span>` with `<div>` but it didn't help either. What am I overlooking here? Obviously, something really very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$("#textContents").html(response);`

Because `<span>` has no value.

Comment: Worked! Several times dealt with already but couldn't recall that, sorry. Waiting for the timer. Thank you. Basically I used to deal with old JavaScript style like `document.getElementById("textContents").innerHTML=response;`